# Who was this person in the Early Modern Period who wrote a manual on writing "good science"?

Tags: science

In a history lecture a while back the teacher spoke about a person who wrote something that (to me) sounded like an instruction manual on how to write "good science". The basic point was that the scientific texts shouldn't include flowery language and should only include the facts.

I thought I remembered it being Robert Boyle, but for him I can only find things about his chemistry, so I'm likely mistaken about him.

Does anyone know who that might have been?

Thanks!

Prior research: I've done extensive web searches about this, but as one might expect, it's difficult to find a person's name (and one  that far back at that) if one only has such vague ideas like having written a manual on "good science". That said, I can say with relative certainty that it was not Robert Boyle.

I've also been reading the basics (see below) to see if anything rings a bell, but so far I've not found anything:

- Morus, Iwan Rhys. 2010. “Placing Performance.” Isis 101 (4): 775–78.
  https://doi.org/10.1086/657476. Shapin, Steven. 2003. “The Image of
  the Man of Science.” In The Cambridge History of Science, edited by
  Roy Porter, 1st ed., 159–83. Cambridge University Press.
  https://doi.org/10.1017/CHOL9780521572439.008. ———. 2010.
- Never Pure:
  Historical Studies of Science as If It Was Produced by People with
  Bodies, Situated in Time, Space, Culture, and Society, and Struggling for Credibility and Authority. Baltimore: Johns Hopkins University
  Press.
- Sleigh, Charlotte. 2011. Literature and Science. Outlining
  Literature. Houndsmill, Basingstoke, Hampshire ; New York: Palgrave
  Macmillan.

Cross-posted to [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/16143/who-was-this-person-in-the-early-modern-period-who-wrote-a-manual-on-writing-go?noredirect=1#comment37802_16143)

Comment: Maybe this should be asked at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Thanks, I've cross-posted over there.

Comment: @ReaderGuy42 You should probably delete this duplicate then, or at least link to that one.

Comment: Did that, thanks!